# CSS text in <p> doesn't expand as it should

Tags: css, width, expand

i have a paragraph within a div, which doesn't expand to fit its contents, but only expands as far as the longest word goes. i have not set the width of either the containing div or the paragraph so i am unsure why it behaves like this?

the site in question is http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z mouse over the green squares

any idea why this happens??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no code in the question body and the link is now dead, rendering the question useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
whitespace: nowrap;
```

On those `<p>` elements.

Comment: beat me to it by a minute :)  one of the lesser known, yet really frustrating css values.

Answer (score 1):

Both your containing `<div>` and your `<p>` are set to `position: absolute`. With no width set for either, I think this means that they “should” both become as narrow as possible given their contents, which is the behaviour you’re seeing. (The relevant section of the spec is [10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), although I’m not absolutely sure I understand it.)

(The alternative would be for them to keep the width they would have if positioned statically, i.e. 100% of their container’s width. If you’re positioning them absolutely, there’s a good chance that would result in part of the content being positioned off-screen.)

When you set `position: absolute`, you should usually set a width too. If you’ve set a value for `left`, you could try setting a value for `right` too instead of fixing the width. (I think older versions of IE might have trouble with that though.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried whitespace: nowrap; on the p element as someone else suggested and it worked

Comment: Excellent — does it work for very long text? I thought very long text might result in the element stretching beyond the width of the page, although I’m not sure. (And obviously that doesn’t matter if you’re not going to have very long text in this element.)

Comment: I suggested the whitespace: nowrap; because I noticed he had explicit <br>s in the <p> element. Otherwise you're right, it would need a set width for the browser to wrap the text.

Comment: @CaseyFoster: ah! Gotcha, didn’t see that.